# Get all values in a dict from a list of keys wherein the same key occures numerous of times

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, key

I have a list with keys and I wish to get the key values from a dict as they occur. Momentarily I have a function which takes a list with keys, but it only returns one occurrence for the same key although the same key occurs numerous of times in the list.

For instance `[1,2,3]` instead of `[1,2,2,2,1,1,3,3]`

Here is my code:

```
key_list = [1,2,2,2,1,1,3,3]

dict_ = {1:'a', 2:b, 3:'c'}

# current function that only returns one occurence per key in the list with keys, key_list`
def get_values_from_dict(dict_, key_list):
    return [v for k, v in dict_.items() if k in key_list]
```

And here is my expected output:

```
['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c']
```

Comment: What do you mean "_momentarily_ I have a function"?

Answer (score 3):

Your list comprehension should be indexing `dict_` with each value in `key_list`:

```
>>> key_list = [1,2,2,2,1,1,3,3]
>>> dict_ = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'}
>>> def get_values_from_dict(dict_, key_list):
...     return [dict_[x] for x in key_list]
...
>>> get_values_from_dict(dict_, key_list)
['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c']
>>>
```

Your current code is incorrect because it is doing something different: it is getting all the values in `dict_` that have keys which are in `key_list`.  In other words, it is filtering the values by `key_list`.

Answer (score 1):

This is already built in to the standard library—it's what [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) does when you give it multiple keys:

```
>>> import operator
>>> key_list = [1,2,2,2,1,1,3,3]
>>> dict_ = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'}
>>> operator.itemgetter(*key_list)(dict)
('a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c')
```

If you need a list instead of a tuple, just convert it:

```
>>> list(operator.itemgetter(*key_list)(dict))
['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c']
```

From the docs:

> Return a callable object that fetches item from its operand using the operand’s `__getitem__()` method. If multiple items are specified, returns a tuple of lookup values.

The cool thing about this is that you can store `itemgetter(key_list)` and repeatedly apply it to different dictionaries, or pass it as a `key` function to a `sort` call, etc. But if you don't need any of that, you can call it directly, as I did above.

The docs also show you how to write the same thing yourself:

```
tuple(obj[item] for item in items)
```

And here, if you want a list, just use a list comprehension instead of a generator expression and the `tuple` function:

```
[obj[item] for item in items]
```

Comment: Didn't see this one coming. Nice library usage.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a one-to-one mapping of your input to output, using the dictionary to do the translation/mapping. Hence, you should iterate on your input list not on the dict items. Code below.

```
def get_values_from_dict(dict_, key_list):
    return [dict_[k] for k in key_list]
```